# dataSnapshot could not get parent push key value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want dataSnapshot to check if "month" exists in its parent's "summary". But dataSnapshot is returning that it does not have "month" in "summary"

```
 ds = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("summary");
 ds.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                //summary
                                String key = ds.getKey();
                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("month")) {

                                    Toast.makeText(newTransaction.this, "got value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(newTransaction.this, "No value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
```

My Firebase Database: I want to check the value (blue line) from its parent(red line)

[My Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wSTU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
String key = ds.getKey();
```

Returns the key of the node on which the reference is pointing to, in this case `summary`. Between the `summary` node and the `month` property, there is another level in your structure, which actually is that pushed key (-MJKC ... xGZX). In order to check if that property exists, you need to use that key in the reference too. Assuming that the `summary` node is a direct node of your Firebase database root, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference keyRef = rootRef.child("summary").child("-MJKC_JkVFpCdCGqxGZX");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("month")) {
            Toast.makeText(newTransaction.this, "got value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(newTransaction.this, "No value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

However, you haven't store that key into a variable, then you should use a query, as below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference summaryRef = rootRef.child("summary");
Query queryByMonth = summaryRef.orderByChild("month")
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(newTransaction.this, "got value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(newTransaction.this, "No value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
queryByMonth.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Hey Nicholas! Have you tried my solution above? Does it work?

Comment: Your solutions works as well. But I tried, instead of calling query I decide decide to directly orderByKey() to sort the key out and use dataSnapshot.exist() to check validation of key.

Comment: Good to hear it worked. Yes, it a good idea to use `orderByKey()` as well.